# Spring Boot 404 on root mapping ("/") deployed on tomat. (resteasy dependency issue)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, resteasy

I have an app made by spring-boot and deployed as a war in a tomcat.

When I run the embedded Tomcat the mapping to / works fine redirecting it to "index.html" but in the tomcat, it only delivers 404.

For example. http://localhost:8080/test/index.html works fine but http://localhost:8080/test/ is not redirecting to index.html. As I will explain below, if I disable resteasy lib, it works fine.

After some hours of debugging following the execution, I realized that the last Servlet who managed the query was "HttpServletDispatcher" from jboss resteasy-jaxrs lib.

Why I'm using that lib? Because the app needs to run the "keycloak-admin-cli" rest lib which depends of "resteasy-client" which depends on "resteasy-jaxrs".

What I've tried without success:

- Excluding the lib -> keycloak-admin-cli stopped working with
  NoClassDefFoundError  **BUT** the root mapping worked well.
- Disabling the Resteasy HttpServletDispatcher -> Nothing happened
- Mapping the servlet on other URL -> Unsuccessful

Now I'm stucked with the ugly workaround of a redirection with an Apache/Nginx but i would know if someone with better knowledge than me in resteasy or spring-boot had some fresh ideas in order to fix it the correct way.

Thank you!

Some lib versions:

- jdk: 1.8
- keycloak: 4.5.0.Final
- resteasy: 3.6.3.Final
- Spring-boot: 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: check your context in tomcat for this app

Comment: which context? with Spring-boot, all contexts XML files are practically empty. As I know

Comment: appcontext. What is your war name that you deployed in the standalone tomcat? are you prefixing your uris with that war name?

Comment: If your war name is `test` are you doing it like this `http://localhost:8080/test/hello`

Comment: Ah yeah, I'll edit my question. http://localhost:8080/test/ -> 404 (I want a redirection to index.html) // http://localhost:8080/test/index.html -> working

Comment: I think its the default home page mappings not redirection

Comment: Have you checked your controller? Maybe redirect can be done from there.

Comment: I tried it with an spring controller but in "/" resteasy intercepts and returns 404. I don't know how to put a handler in / without breaking the architecture